# libev.so.4 does not exist (but it does)

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pip

I'm trying to install pyev on Ubuntu using pip but I get this error. libev.so.4 does indeed exist, I found it at /usr/local/lib along with other libev.so files so I assume it's simply a matter of python isn't looking in the right spot or the .so's got put in the wrong place by mistake.

```
$ pip install pyev
Collecting pyev
Using cached pyev-0.9.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-cBE9pk/pyev/setup.py", line 57, in <module>
    check_version(libev_version(), min_libev_version, "libev")
  File "/tmp/pip-build-cBE9pk/pyev/setup.py", line 48, in libev_version
    libev_dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(libev_dll_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libev.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So my question is where the libev.so files should live, or, if they're in the correct place, why can't python find them and how do I fix it?

EDIT: Python version 2.7.10, Pip version 7.1.0 both downloaded and installed today (Python manually, pip using get-pip.py)

`locate libev` gives me a long list of files for libevent, libevolution, and libevview. Pretty much the only thing related to libev was usr/lib/libevdocument.so.1, usr/lib/libevdocument.so.1.0.0, and /usr/share/doc/libevdocument1 (which included AUTHORS, NEWS.gz, README, TODO, changelog.Debian.gz, and copyright). Nothing in local for some reason

EDIT 2.0
Running it as sudo (can't believe I forgot that) gives me a weird error message "The directory /home/username/.cache/pip/http or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag." and then proceeded to redownload pyev-0.9.0.tar.gz and run into the same error of not finding libev.so.4.

Running it as 'sudo -H pip install pyev' gave me the first error message again (using the cached pyev). What does sudo -H do anyway? I couldn't find anything about it online or in the sudo help message.

Comment: What does `locate libev` tell you?

Comment: Also `python --version` and `pip --version`

Comment: Python 2.7.10 and pip 7.1.0 (both downloaded and installed today)

Comment: Did you try `sudo pip install pyev`? Or you are executing it with root account?

Comment: Added the results of sudo and sudo -H to the question

Answer (score 0):

Looking at another partition that has libev properly installed I was able to find the libev.so files under usr/lib rather than usr/local/lib. Copying them to that folder and running sudo -H pip install pyev seems to have properly installed pyev. Thanks for your help.